# how to update posted time locally in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, backend

I wanna update time for post when user created post.
i tried some method but didnt get expected results.

Note - im storing created post in array. (locally)

```
const posts = [];

const addedDate = new Date();
const addedTime = addedDate.getMinutes();

exports.getIndex = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index', {
    pageTitle: 'NewsFeed',
    path: '/',
    post: posts,
    time: addedTime,
  });
};

exports.getPost = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('post', {
    pageTitle: 'Create Post',
    path: '/post',
  });
};

exports.postAddPost = (req, res, next) => {
  posts.unshift({ title: req.body.title });

  res.redirect('/');
};
```

**Here is the pic of post
time is not updating
i want to time auto update
like
1min ago - 1hr ago - 1 day ago**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTD02.png

Answer (score 0):

Use momentJS library. they have every format you'd need. The one you want is FromNow.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting.
ill try.

Comment: momentJS has stopped the development and may get deprecated, Alternatively you can use Luxon by moment team.

https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you create "addedDate" once when you run your application using the current time. When you show your news feed, you pass along the minutes of the time that you started your application.

I assume that you're trying to display when a post was created. In this case you should add the current time to your post object:

```
exports.postAddPost = (req, res, next) => {
  posts.unshift({ title: req.body.title, added: new Date() });

  res.redirect('/');
};
```

Then in your template you would iterate over the posts array that you pass as "post" and access the properties via "post.title" and "post.added".

I'm not sure what you had in mind regarding the minutes. If you intended to display something like "posted 5 minutes ago", then you could create another Date in your template and compare it with the "added" property of your post to figure out the difference.

The difference can be calculated fairly easily with vanilla JavaScript, you can just subtract two Date objects and get the difference in milliseconds:

```
const post = {
  title: 'Title',
  added: new Date(),
};

// some time later
const now = new Date();
const milliseconds = now - post.added;
const seconds = ms / 1000;
const minutes = seconds / 60;
```

And so on.

Comment: thanks for suggeting.
could you please guide, how can create and compare the difference?
https://stackoverflow.com/users/4409162/marcel-herd

Comment: im wondering that how can i use this? and where should i use this?
https://stackoverflow.com/users/4409162/marcel-herd

Comment: I would add this to getIndex and pass "minutes" along as property in the res.render call. Then you can access "minutes" in your template. When you create a post, it would save that time in the post, and when you access the feed, it would generate the time when the access happens. When you refresh the page, it should run again and the "minutes" would be different.